# Название вина

Tags: фонетика

Все-таки как правильно: "бастАрдо" или "бастардО"? Говорят и так, и так. В университете мы учили, что "бастАрдо".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласна с Вами. "БастАрдо"